# how to link server Images in Indesign using XML

Tags: xml, xslt, adobe-indesign

I am using XML as input for indesign,

I can format paragraph styles and character styles using XSLT, but I do not know how to link a server image that should load inside indesign when flowing XML in indesign.

Can anyone please give a suggestion in this.

**I tried :**

```
<xlink href="file://209.11.157.44:803/Images/2/aec030af5c7a4011ac017e948baa84d7.jpg"/>
```

Kindly note this is a server image, I want to load this image in indesign.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1):

You cannot load images from an external server with InDesign/XML workflows. Images have to be local.

Only possible solution yet not tried, may consist in EmeraSoft plugin : eLink allowing to links files from external locations such as a server. However it seems like the plugin is no longer avaialble.
http://www.emerasoft.com/

Other solution may consist in using 65bit EasyCatalog software both allowing XML import and external images import.

Eventually have a routine to download files prior to use them.